# How to scroll down entire div and how to highlight active div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I just wanted to know that how can I shift entire div on just one scroll.

Actually in my website (http://codinghub.ga/development.html) I have contents in different divs. I want to shift entire div on scrolling just once. Like in https://www.kingoapp.com/ and also how to highlight active div as in this website.

Comment: For this you need to add third part library like `fullpsge.js`. https://www.kingoapp.com/ also using this

Comment: post the relevant code ;P

Comment: @Sahil Mangotra Did you check my code, by any chance?

Comment: Yup @purvik7373  ,I studied your code but I thought I might have to edit entire code of website which my brain is not allowing to do .I will try it in next version of website.. But thanks I will surely use it in next version.

Comment: @SahilMangotra Okay Thanks, mate, If in future you face any issue please let us know.

Comment: @purvik7373 Sure, thanx for help, :)

Answer (score 2):

[### FullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/)

A simple and easy to use plugin to create fullscreen scrolling websites (also known as single page websites or onepage sites). It allows the creation of fullscreen scrolling websites, as well as adding some landscape sliders inside the sections of the site.

**Example :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#menu',
    css3: true
  });
});
```

```css
/* Custom CSS
 * --------------------------------------- */
body{
 font-family: arial,helvetica;
 color: #333;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.wrap{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 960px;
 position: relative;
}
h1{
 font-size: 6em; 
}
p, h2{
 font-size: 2em;
}
h2{
 color:inherit;
}
.section{
 text-align:center;
}
#menu li {
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #000;
 background:#fff;
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
            border-radius: 10px; 
}
#menu li.active{
 background:#666;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
 color: #fff;
}
#menu li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #000;
}
#menu li.active a:hover{
 color: #000;
}
#menu li:hover{
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
#menu li a,
#menu li.active a{
 padding: 9px 18px;
 display:block;
}
#menu li.active a{
 color: #fff;
}
#menu{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 height: 40px;
 z-index: 70;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
}
#section0 img,
#section1 img{
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
} 
#section2 img,
#section3 img{
 margin: 20px 0 0 52px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">First section</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second section</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third section</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage">Fourth section</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section active" id="section0">
    <h1>Single Page Demo</h1>
    <img src="http://static.webpie.net/files/11/images/web68-logo-small.png" alt="web68" />
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="slide active">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1>Create Sliders</h1>
        <p>Not only vertical scrolling but also horizontal scrolling. With fullPage.js you will be able to add horizontal sliders in the most simple way ever.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="intro">
        <img src="http://static.webpie.net/files/11/images/web68-logo-small.png" alt="web68" />
        <h1>Simple</h1>
        <p>Easy to use. Configurable and customizable.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="intro">
        <img src="http://static.webpie.net/files/11/images/web68-logo-small.png" alt="web68" />
        <h1>Cool</h1>
        <p>It just looks cool. Impress everybody with a simple and modern web design!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="intro">
        <img src="http://static.webpie.net/files/11/images/web68-logo-small.png" alt="web68" />
        <h1>Compatible</h1>
        <p>Working in modern and old browsers too! IE 8 users don't have the fault of using that horrible browser! Lets give them a chance to see your site in a proper way!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Easy to use plugin</h1>
      <p>HTML markup example to define 4 sections.</p>
      <img src="http://static.webpie.net/files/11/images/web68-logo-small.png" alt="web68" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section3">
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Working On Tablets</h1>
    </div>
    <img src="http://static.webpie.net/files/11/images/web68-logo-small.png" alt="web68" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Would you please check above snippet? I thinks it's more helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer..

Add fullpage.js

And set ID in each and every mail DIV..

**Example:** https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/vertical-and-horizontal-scrolling-with-fullpagejs--cms-24215

I hope it's helpful for you..